# Attempting to store values stored in variables into SQL Database

Tags: php, mysql, database

Hello quick question regarding storage of variables in a mySQL database in php.

```
if(count($_SESSION['cart'])>0) {

$ids = array();
foreach ($_SESSION['cart'] as $id => $value) {
    array_push($ids, $id);
}

$stmt = $food->readByIds($ids);

$total = 0;
$item_count = 0;

while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    extract($row);

    $quantity = $_SESSION['cart'][$id]['quantity'];
    $sub_total = $price * $quantity;

    //echo "<div class='product-id' style='display:none;'>{$id}</div>";
    //echo "<div class='product-name'>{$name}</div>";

    // =================
    echo "<div class='cart-row'>";
    echo "<div class='col-md-8'>";

    echo "<div class='food-name m-b-10px'><h4>{$name}</h4></div>";
    echo $quantity > 1 ? "<div>{$quantity} items</div>" : "<div>{$quantity} item</div>";

    echo "</div>";

    echo "<div class='col-md-4'>";
    echo "<h4>&#36;" . number_format($price, 2, '.', ',') . "</h4>";
    echo "</div>";
    echo "</div>";
    // =================

    $item_count += $quantity;
    $total += $sub_total;
}

$sql = "INSERT INTO food_orders (food_list, food_total, created_on) VALUES (:$name, :$total, :current_timestamp)";

$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);

$stmt->bindParam(':$name', $_POST['food_list'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':$total', $_POST['food_total'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':current_timestamp',$_POST['created_on'], PDO::PARAM_STR);

$stmt->execute();
```

Currently, I am attempting to store the values calculated into the database under the $_POST tag, but I am constantly thrown the error:

```
Warning: PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: 
parameter was not defined in C:\wamp64\www\phpFoodSitewithCart\charge.php
```

Is there a better way to store the variables or sync them properly?

Thanks for the look and the help.

Answer (score 1):

Placeholders should look like `:name` not `:$name`. By using `$name` anywhere inside a double-quoted string you're asking for string interpolation to kick in and unless `$name` is defined as something that basically removes it from the string, leaving just `:` which is not valid. The placeholder goes invisible.